# Setting indicators based in index per row in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for an efficient way to set a indicators from zero to a known number (which differs for each row).

e.g.

```
 a =
 array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

and I know the vector with the index when a goes from 1 to zero.

```
b = [3, 1, 6, 2, 8]
```

Rather than filling all the rows of a using a for-loop, I want to know if there is a fast way to set these indicators.

Comment: have you tried using a count for each row? Is the other INT always going to be a 1? will there ever be 1s after the 0s begin? need more info.

Comment: yes, it is always 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`outer-comparison`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)  on ranged array vs. `b` -

```
In [16]: ncols = 9

In [17]: b
Out[17]: [3, 1, 6, 2, 8]

In [19]: np.greater.outer(b,np.arange(ncols)).view('i1')
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Other similar ways to express the same -

```
(np.asarray(b)[:,None] > np.arange(ncols)).view('i1')
(np.asarray(b)[:,None] > np.arange(ncols)).astype(int)
```

With `b` being an array, simplifies further, as we can skip the array conversion with `np.asarray(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of is:

```
result=[]
for row in array:
    result.append(row.tolist().index(0))

print(result)

[3, 1, 6, 2, 8]
```

The reason this works is, that list has a method called index, which tells the first occurrence of a specific item in the list. So I am iterating over this 2-dimentional array, converting each of it to list and using index of 0 on each.

You can store these values into another list and append to it for each row and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasting to do an outer comparison:

```
b = np.asarray([3, 1, 6, 2, 8])

a = (np.arange(b.max() + 1) < b[:, None]).astype(int)
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```